# How to discover a list of physical audio input channels?

Tags: linux, audio, sdl, portaudio, pulseaudio

I am trying to make a simple studio recording application.
I have multiple sound input devices, and would like to record them all simultaneously.

How do I discover all physical audio inputs?

When I use `sounddevice.query_devices()`, I get a lot of *virtual devices* and a lot of *virtual* input channels, that contain no data:

```
>>> sd.query_devices()

  0 HDA Intel PCH: HDMI 0 (hw:0,3), ALSA (0 in, 8 out)
  1 HDA Intel PCH: HDMI 1 (hw:0,7), ALSA (0 in, 8 out)
  2 HDA Intel PCH: HDMI 2 (hw:0,8), ALSA (0 in, 8 out)
  3 hdmi, ALSA (0 in, 8 out)
  4 pulse, ALSA (32 in, 32 out)
* 5 default, ALSA (32 in, 32 out)
  6 /dev/dsp, OSS (16 in, 16 out)
```

I am only interested in real devices, and real input channels.

When I query microphone devices with `pacmd` and then `list-sources` I get two channels giving *fake* stereo, even though the device is mono:

```
$ pacmd
>>> list-sources
...
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
```

Is there a way to either query PulseAudio, or PortAudio to get *physical* input channels? And their parameters (so that I can pick sample rate etc.)

Comment: I don't think that's possible with PortAudio. You could try to scan for `(hw:X,Y)` in the device name, but I'm not sure if that matches exactly the devices you would like to see.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if there is any other API that would make it easy?

Comment: I found it is possible in PulseAudio.

Answer (score 1):

It seems best to do more complex things possible in [PulseAudio](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/). Here I found the link to the [example program](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/Developer/Clients/Samples/AsyncDeviceList/).
Unfortunately it is complex API that requires one to:

1. First initialize event loop with `pa_mainloop_new`, and `pa_mainloop_get_api`.
2. Then create a new context with `pa_context_new`, `pa_context_connect`, and `pa_context_set_state_callback`.
3. In the context callback, one recognizes context initialization and starts enumeration (`pa_context_get_source_info_list` or `pa_context_get_sink_info_list`).
4. Enumeration itself is performed by callbacks too.

Luckily it seems supported on all major platforms (I used Linux and MacOS X). Given the scope of interface, I will probably keep using PulseAudio for all my future audio projects.

Similar enumeration for PipeWire API, which is newer: https://docs.pipewire.org/page_tutorial2.html